# How to set specified date for a new Jira issue?

Tags: php, soap, jira

Created date for a new Jira issue is always `NOW();` How do we set a specified date for a new Jira issue?

```
$soapClient = 
    new SoapClient("http://jira:9090/rpc/soap/jirasoapservice-v2?wsdl");
$token = $soapClient->login('user', 'pass');
$issue=array(
    'created' => '2005-04-14T18:00:00Z',
    'type'=>3,
    'project'=>'XXX',
    'assignee'=>'user1',
    'reporter'=>'user1',
    'description'=>'test',
    'summary'=>'test'
);
$soapClient->createIssue($token, $issue);
```

Comment: `created date` and `updated date` in any system are mostly auto-generated and will not be user-editable? What is your use case to change it?

Comment: I need to move old tasks from Sugar CRM to JIRA keeping the original date of creation.

Comment: Ah! That's a valid use case. Just curious if you have already looked at https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Migrating+from+Other+Issue+Trackers...

Comment: https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-13888

Comment: Thanks for the link @SergeyL. Seems soap interface is not the right way for migration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though your use case is valid, from Jira's point of view, an issue is always created when it really gets created within Jira.

From Jira 6.4 API documentation (https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#d2e4329):

"The fields that can be set on create, in either the fields parameter or the update parameter can be determined using the /rest/api/2/issue/createmeta resource. If a field is not configured to appear on the create screen, then it will not be in the createmeta, and a field validation error will occur if it is submitted."